# Create new table from current table inner joining 6 tables

Tags: sql, create-table

I am very new to SQL, so I apologize in advance if my query doesn't look perfect. I am trying to create a new table for this statement. I have 6 tables joined on the primary key.  I tried Create table as (but it does not work).  If anyone could please me, it would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT *      
FROM DATABASE.Table1
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table2
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table2.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table3
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table3.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table4
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table4.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table5
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table5.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table6
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table6.PrimaryKey
WHERE PrimaryKey = ‘1’
```

Comment: Probably giving you the *ambiguous column* error. You should select the columns you need explicity

Comment: `does not work` isnt helpful, post the error message. The correct option is `CREATE TABLE AS `, so is better if you show the compete query. But Im with GurV with that query you will have six fields called `"PrimaryKey"`

Answer (score 0):

So you want one table with all the fields from each of the source tables, is that right? You can use a SELECT.... INTO:

```
SELECT [Field List] INTO MyNewConsolidatedTable      
FROM DATABASE.Table1
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table2
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table2.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table3
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table3.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table4
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table4.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table5
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table5.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN DATABASE.Table6
ON DATABASE.Table1.PrimaryKey = DATABASE.Table6.PrimaryKey
WHERE PrimaryKey = ‘1’
```

Note that you will need to replace [Field List] and enumerate all of the fields that you want in the new table, because otherwise you'll have 6 fields called PrimaryKey, which SQL won't allow.